# react-mapbox-gl event polygon click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

i'm trying to work with this react-friendly wrapper written by https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl.

I have trouble about how to add to event listener to polygon generated from geojson using react-mapbox-gl. Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import ReactMapboxGl, { GeoJSONLayer, Layer, Feature } from "react-mapbox-gl"

const position = [106.822700,-6.174500]

class MapView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      geojson: {}
    };
  }

  _onClick = () => {
    console.log('polygon click')
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let url = './json/poly.json'
    fetch(url)
   .then( (response) => {
     return response.json()
   })
   .then( (json) => {
     this.setState({
       geojson: json
     })
   })
   .catch( (err) => {
     //error
   })
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <ReactMapboxGl
            style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8"
            accessToken="YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN"
            center={position}
            containerStyle={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}>

            <GeoJSONLayer
              data={this.state.geojson}
              fillPaint={{
                "fill-color": "#ff0000"
              }}/>
      </ReactMapboxGl>
    </div>
  }
}  

ReactDOM.render(
  <MapView />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Comment: Hey Yasin, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi @romeboards, as suggested below, i'm gonna try react-mapbox-gl ^2.3. Now, they support mouse event handler for GeoJson component.

Answer (score 0):

react-mapbox-gl ^2.3 now include mouse event handler for the different shapes of your GeoJson component, have a look at the documentation https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/API.md#geojsonlayer